# How to pass data from a form to a php function to javascript to draw on a canvas without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

I am looking to create a basic graphic calculator using only html, php, and javascript. The code below refreshes the page so the javascript never gets a chance to draw the graph. The way this is supposed to work is that the php grabs the data from the form and outputs the results of the equation point by point into an array. The array is passed to the javascript which uses the index of the array for the x value and the value at that index for the y value. I tried having the form target a separate iframe but the graph still isn't drawing and I am not sure why. I heard there is a way to do this with AJAX but the current challenge is to do this with just html,css if needed, javascript, and php.

```
   <?php
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
        $val1 = htmlentities($_POST['val1']);
        $val2 = htmlentities($_POST['val2']);
        $val3 = htmlentities($_POST['val3']);
        $results;
        for($i = 0; $i < 530; $i++)
        {
            $results[i] = pow($i,$val1) + $i*$val2 + $val3;
            if($results[i] >= 530)
                break;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="example4.php" method="POST">
        x^:
        <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>
       +x*:
        <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></input>
       +1*:
        <input type="text" name="val3" id="val3"></input>

        <input type="submit" value="send"></input>
    </form>
    <canvas id="c" height="530" width="530" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var b = document.body;
              var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
              var a = c.getContext('2d');
              var data = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
              a.beginPath();
              a.moveTo(0,530);
              a.strokeStyle="black";
              for(var i=0; i < data.length-1; i++))
              {
                a.moveTo(i,data[i]);
                a.lineTo(i+1,data[i+1]);
                a.stroke();
              }
          </script>
```

Comment: You do have the other parts of the html document right- like the <html>, <head>, <body> tags?

Comment: If you add the following javascript `console.dir(data);` after the json_encode line what is the output to your console? (ctrl + shift + i in chrome(windows))

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are setting data equal to the JSON string not to an array object.

Can you change the line that reads:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
```

To the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>");
```

EDIT: I reread your question and see you want the php variables at the top of the page to be set by the user through the form on the page.  The problem with how you are surrently thinking about it is that PHP is run on the server and HTML/Javascript is rendered and run on the user's browser.  So all of the php has already executed before the user sees the form.

You can run php from an HTML page though by using AJAX.  So you will AJAXing to a php file that performs the computations and builds the array and ultimately echo's the JSON of the array.  The JavaScript will then handle the result like I talked about in my original answer above.

For an AJAX tutorial that deals with the components you will need: http://www.simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/simple_ajax

Comment: Just tried this and the page is still refreshing without drawing the graph

Comment: I just read it. I don't know AJAX yet so unless you can give me a quick lesson in how to set that up Id need to use just php, javascript, and html. Is there any way I could structure the page so that the php is only read and executed after I click on submit?

Comment: PHP is run on the server that hosts the webpage.  The browser downloads HTML from the server and the server runs any php that is in the file before returning the HTML.  For that reason, the client never sees, executes, or is otherwise aware of php.  Whenever you realize that you're going to have to run php without refreshing the page(a common situation) you are going to have to use AJAX to execute a .php file.  See the link I've placed in my answer for a tutorial that will help